# Tomcat don't work with Nginx reverse proxy

Tags: tomcat, nginx, reverse-proxy

I tried to hide my Apache Tomcat behind Nginx . I want to realize such scheme:
[Http Client] <- https -> [Nginx] <- http -> [Tomcat]
Tomcat 8.0.53 and Nginx 1.16.1 installed at PC with external ip address and Windows server. 
Single Tomcat works in https mode - it accepts connections on 443 port.
But with Nginx at front i've got ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR or ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS(depends on my tries of configuring them) while trying access site.

Tomcat:

```
<Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" address="127.0.0.1"
        connectionTimeout="20000"
        Server="Apache"
        SSLEnabled="false" secure="false"
        proxyName="localhost" proxyPort="443"
    />

    <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               maxThreads="200" enableLookups="false" acceptCount="200"
               scheme="https" secure="true"
               SSLEnabled="false" sslProtocol="TLS" proxyPort="443" 
               SSLCertificateFile="${catalina.base}/conf/platform.crt"
               SSLCertificateKeyFile="${catalina.base}/conf/platform.key"
               SSLCACertificateFile="${catalina.base}/conf/ca.crt"
               Server="Apache"
    />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Alias>localhost</Alias>

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="site_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
```

NGINX

```
      server {  

    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name my.foo.bar;
    listen [::]:443;

    ssl_certificate C:/NewDev/nginx-1.16.1/conf/platform.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key C:/NewDev/nginx-1.16.1/conf/platform.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;



### default dest for backend at Tomcat
        location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 120;
        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_buffering     off;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
  }
```

This error is found in nginx' error.log:

```
2019/12/23 17:18:35 [error] 5752#5116: *1 connect() failed (10061: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it) while connecting to upstream, client: 109.73.8.14, server: my.foo.bar, request: "GET /main?sysname=logon HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://[::1]:8080/main?sysname=logon", host: "my.foo.bar"

2019/12/23 17:18:57 [warn] 5752#5116: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: 109.73.8.14, server: my.foo.bar, request: "GET /main?sysname=logon HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://[::1]:8080/main?sysname=logon", host: "my.foo.bar"
```

I think, that problem is in Tomcat config, which I want to work in http mode only. But I can't locate where exactly it is.

Comment: 1 Is tomcat really working? Please execute `netstat -nutpl | grep 8080`.
2 What says tomcat's log file?

Comment: 1) I've got windows server - I think, that grep isn't available there :) Tomcat is really working through 443, cause he serves rest requests and returns some frontend.
2) in catalina log everything is ok: everything starts ok, only INFO messages.

Comment: Expanding on @metallic reply, in the cmd window, execute `netstat -ano | findstr /l :8080` to verify tomcat is started and listening on the port

Comment: Consider adding `proxy_redirect  off;` in your nginx-configuration. The ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS usually means there is an infinite redirect loop